# Absolute Referencing Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to extract source data from a different sheet from my workbook in order to tell how many employees were working for our company's branches in each financial year from 2020-2025.

[image]

(In this SS, I have the Employee_Num sheet, where I'm trying to extract the number of employees in each financial year for every day of the financial year)

[image]

(Here I present the source, where I have the numbers allocated to each branch based on a location code)

The column titled "Source Data" is supposed to have a vlookup formula that extracts the employees based on the financial year and based on the location.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,SourceData!B:H, 
    IF(Employee_Num!C2=SourceData!$C$1,2,
    IF(Employee_Num!C2=SourceData!$D$1,3,
    IF(Employee_Num!C2=SourceData!$E$1,4,
    IF(Employee_Num!C2=SourceData!$F$1,5, 
    IF(Employee_Num!C2=SourceData!$G$1,6, 
    IF(Employee_Num!C2=SourceData!$H$1,7,1))))))
,0)
```

I feel I'm getting very close with this formula but for some reason it only displays the data for 2020 :(

Comment: I'm not fully understanding your question in relation to your first screenshot. To me, 11 appears to be the right outcome when you looking up C01 in 2020?

Comment: It seems to me that your formula is working though? I tried different years and locations and it appears to be working fine?

Comment: @JvdV It is working, I'm just blind, I'm sorry to have wasted your time. I think I had a problem with my Work desktop. Thank you.